# How to Access a List through a key?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, key

I have a program that has a save file full of lists. It Loads up the Items by making lists. It gets the Names from the file too. Since I couldn't "unstring" a string so I put the names as keys. My problem is re-saving the lists when you are done using the program. I cant seem to access the contents inside the list to write them to a file. I have another List with keys so I can access the Names.

```
ListKey = {1:'Food', 2:'Veggie'}
List={'Food':['apple','pear','grape'], 'Veggies':['carrot','Spinach','Potato']}

file.write(ListKey[1]) #works fine
currentList=ListKey[1]
file.write(List[currentList[1]]) #Doesn't Work
```

When I try to do the code above, I get a Key Error, I know it is trying to write the 'o' in food. Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: When you say you want to "access the contents inside the list" you mean inside the `List`? `List` is a `dictionary`. What do you want to write to the file exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access a value inside your key pairs. Try:

```
List[currentList][0] to access 'apple'
List[currentList][1] to access 'pear'
```

etc...

alternatively if you want all the values, it would look like

```
List[currentList]  or 
List['Food']
```

Hope this helps, just your syntax of how to access the list inside.

edit: 
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions 
(added link to data structure docs)

Answer (score 1):

`currentList[1]` is just the value `o`, use:

```
file.write(List[currentList])
```

Comment: `ListKey` instead of `List`.

Answer (score 0):

`ListKey = {1:'Food', 2:'Veggie'}
    List={'Food':['apple','pear','grape'], 'Veggies':     ['carrot','Spinach','Potato']}
    currentList = ListKey[1]   #'Food'
    currentList[1] # 'o'`

You are actually indexing into the string "Food". Hence currentList[1] is 'o'. Since List has no key 'o' you get at key error.